# Proper usage for MvxFileDownloadCache.Clear

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to cleanup unwanted http image data that I have loaded via MvxImageViewLoader.

I've found the function clear in the FileDownloadCache which seems to do what I need.

```
var downloadCache = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileDownloadCache>();
downloadCache.Clear(_imageChart1ViewLoader.ImageUrl);
```

Periodically it calls a function (once a second by the looks of it) which deletes the files in the private list

```
private readonly List<string> _toDeleteFiles = new List<string>();
```

Clear adds the image by url to that list.

Except once I call this function I'm still able to see the image. I.e. it stays in memory.

So really I need to know where is a good place to be calling Clear and am I using it in the correct way. Currently I call it every time I exit my DetailView which downloads an image from a URL.

MvvmCross v4.2.2 (latest)